# Automatically create zip file from some content's file field (Plone 3)

Tags: plone

I have a folderish content type as well as a child type inside. The child type has a file field.

```
Font family (folderish)
 - Font (child)
   - Font file 1 (field)
 - Font (child)
   - Font file 2
```

I am wondering if I can automatically generate a .zip file which contains all the files of it's children, which I can then link to in the parent's interface.

If so, can you outline the approach? Do I need to use BLOB? I notice there is a product called zipFileTransport, is there a way to add this action to a rule?

Comment: Python standard library comes with zipping tools. You need to create a browser view which iterates through the content and generates zip data, then streams this data to the browser. No blobs needed. No needed to use disk, you can work with memory buffers in Python. How to iterate child items is described in collective-docs.plone.org

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend instead of making a custom content type with a file field, extend the ATFile content type so that you get all the file-like behavior for free.  From there you could use [collective.zipfiletransport](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.zipfiletransport) as long as you only allow your file content type within your folder content type.